# Schrödinger representation for the Heisenberg group.

Tags: representation-theory, heisenberg-group

I'm studying the Schrodinger representation for the Heisenberg Group in Foundations of Harmonic Analysis by Rottensteiner (https://services.phaidra.univie.ac.at/api/object/o:1265111/get)

Studying this document, I have not been able to understand two facts regarding the representations. I attach the images.

[image]

[image]

For simplicity, I will consider $n=1$.

\begin{align}
(t,p,q)\mapsto i(tI+qx+hD)
\end{align} where $D=-i\partial_x$

**Question 1.** Why are antisymmetric operators on the Schwartz space considered in this representation? Is it because if $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ then $xf(x),\, Df(x),\, \in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ ?

**Question 2.**   Why is the space of bounded linear operators on $L^2(R)$ considered? The exponential $\mathrm{e}^{(i(htI+qx+hpD)}$ is bounded on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?
Thank you.

Comment: Exponentiation of an anti-Hermitian operator gives a unitary operator.

Comment: Exponentiation with the definition of power series?
Where I coud found "Exponentiation of an anti-Hermitian operator gives a unitary operator"? reference?

Comment: No, for an unbounded operator exponentiation is defined by the spectral theorem or Stone's theorem on one-parameter groups.  For a bounded operator the power series is valid.  You can check informally to see that in the power series expansion, $\exp(qX)$ is multiplication by $\exp(itq)$, $\exp(hD)$ is translation by $h$ (or $-h$, not sure) and these are both unitary operators.  I think applied on the Schwartz space these series probably converge.

Comment: Thanks you. Could you tell me if I understood it correctly?
If $A$ is a skew-symmetric on a space of functions $S$, then $e^{A}$ (or $e^{iA}$?) is an unitary operator on $S$? This is for Stone's theorem?

Comment: @Chad K  Stone's theorem implies that the exponentiation has sense. This exponential coincides with the exponential as power series?